# trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed in Angular

Tags: angular

i got this error while trying to display fetched data from an API :

Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

this is my app.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';
  courses: Company[];

  // (2) Inject
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) {
    this.courses = [];
  }
 


ngOnInit(): void { 


this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/').subscribe((courses: Company[]) => {
  // (4) Store
  this.courses = courses;
});

} 
}
```

this is my app.component.html :

```
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr > 
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
        {{ course }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</tr> </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, problem is in the way you are setting `courses` property inside your subscription handler. `get` call returns and `object` and not an array which is why you are seeing the issue.

Update you `subscription` function to:

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/').subscribe((response: any) => {
  // (4) Store
  this.courses = response.courses; // response.data.courses not sure, you will have to check it 
});
```

Comment: still not working in HTML not displaying anything .

Comment: Help us to help you...paste what response is (console.log it)

Comment: @silver123 do `console.log` inside subscription handler, without knowing response structure I cannot say for sure what will work.